# POST/GET Request w/JavaScript & Python files all together with an HTML site

Tags: javascript, python, html, post, get

I have an HTML site with nothing but a button with an on-click event that will call a JavaScript function with the sole purpose of generating a pop-up window. Said pop up should contain the response from a GET request made on a separate python file that has some code to talk to a payment gateway api. **The problem** is that the JavaScript pop-up comes up blank because I don't know how to integrate all 3 separate files. I have consulted tons of material with no luck. I have to mention that it will be better if no extra libraries are added up as this is for a future Odoo (ERP) implementation and that platform doesn't accept importing python libraries other that a selected few (as far as I know). The connection to the API works when you run the code via terminal, postman, insomnia, etc...I just need some help figuring out how to put everything together to come up via web browser.

Any help is greatly appreciated. This is the HTML Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Serfinsa</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Boton de Pago -->
    <btPagar onclick="popupwindow()">
        <a href="https://test.serfinsacheckout.com:8080/" id="btPagar" style="float: left;">
            <img src="https://test.serfinsacheckout.com:8080/img/btnpagar.png">
        </a>
    </btPagar>

</body>
<script src="serfinsa.js"></script>
<script src="https://test.serfinsacheckout.com:8080/Scripts/Serfinsa.Pay.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" 
        integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
</html>
```

This is the JavaScript POP-UP Window:

```
function popupwindow(url, title, w, h) {
    let left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
    let top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
    popup = window.open(url, title, 'toolbar=no, location=0, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top = '+top+', left = '+left+' ');
    return popup;
}
```

This is the Python POST/GET request:

```
import warnings
import contextlib
import requests
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

old_merge_environment_settings = requests.Session.merge_environment_settings

@contextlib.contextmanager
def no_ssl_verification():
    opened_adapters = set()

    def merge_environment_settings(self, url, proxies, stream, verify, cert):
        # Verification happens only once per connection so we need to close
        # all the opened adapters once we're done. Otherwise, the effects of
        # verify=False persist beyond the end of this context manager.
        opened_adapters.add(self.get_adapter(url))

        settings = old_merge_environment_settings(self, url, proxies, stream, verify, cert)
        settings['verify'] = False

        return settings

    requests.Session.merge_environment_settings = merge_environment_settings

    try:
        with warnings.catch_warnings():
            warnings.simplefilter('ignore', InsecureRequestWarning)
            yield
    finally:
        requests.Session.merge_environment_settings = old_merge_environment_settings

        for adapter in opened_adapters:
            try:
                adapter.close()
            except:
                pass

idcliente = '97bd8cf4-e894-4cb5-b8cc-3fc31f79c81a'
valor = 35.00
id_transaccioncomercio = 1001

get_url = 'https://test.serfinsacheckout.com:8080/Pay/GateWay?token=' + idcliente + '&idTransaccion=2565'
post_url = 'https://test.serfinsacheckout.com:8080/api/PayApi/TokeyTran'

payload = {
    'TokeyComercio': idcliente,
    'Monto': valor,
    'IdTransaccionCliente': id_transaccioncomercio
}

with no_ssl_verification():
    r = requests.get(get_url)
    # print("Status Code: {} [OK]".format(r.status_code))
    print(r.content)

with no_ssl_verification():
    r = requests.post(post_url, data = payload)
    print(r.json())

Session = requests.Session()
Session.verify = True
```

Comment: You would ideally need a framework imo, look at django/flask.

Comment: I know that Django is ideal for it. However, that won't be supported once I move that code into Odoo...there's gotta be another way

Comment: From my experience, I don't see a way of doing this without a library/framework. Also, is the use of python necessary in this case? You can use javascript to do the exact API gateway implementation in python.

Comment: Somebody suggested creating a python server within my script. I guess it doesn't hurt trying it out....and yeah for sure it will be easier to do it from the same JavaScript file...problem is I don't know how to re-write all that NO_SSL code in JavaScript and for some reason the POST request is not getting through on JavaScript....do you know how to re-write it?

Comment: I am afraid, I don't. But I am sure if you research you will find a solution. Once you got some working code then you can post here for more help/clarification.